# Content Search Webpart missing "new" Items from List Query

Tags: web-part, 2016, content-query-web-part, query, content-search-web-part

I've created a Content Search WebPart on my SharePoint 2016 site page, and it's missing items from the list which have the "new" tag on them, meaning they were newly created.

The following is what my Query Looks like in the Advanced mode:
**ListID:B4BA5478-6239-4DC3-806A-D04BEFB6284A**

And the list is Sorted by "Created" in Descending Order, which is the default sort.

That's it. I've even tried to sort the list in other ways, but could not find those items. Also, when I create a normal List Webpart, it shows these new items. So the issue seems to be only in the Content Search Webpart.

Is there some kind of setting to include the new items? Any help would be really appreciated as it's been a few days since I'm trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a search web part a search crawl has to run before they will show up in the web part.  The list view web part is not dependent on search, this is why they show up in the list view web part but not the content search web part.

Comment: I'd just add to evilfoamy's answer by saying that the Content Query Web Part should display instant results and does not require any kind of search crawl (i.e. a refresh) to run before showing items that already exist.

Comment: Thank You @evilfoamy!! I modified the search crawl settings to update more frequently and that seems to do the job. The page updates every 10-15 minutes.

Also thanks a lot @Tally, didn't know about the Content Query. This will be useful in my other webparts :)